# Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException when deploying my symfony app to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, symfony, heroku-toolbelt

Please I have an erro when trying to deploy my symfony 3 application to heroku.

That is my parameters.yml.dist:

```
parameters:
    database_host:     sql7.freemysqlhosting.net
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     sql8125248
    database_user:     sql8125248
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_password: R2NgGhUjO8
    # You should uncomment this if you want use pdo_sqlite
    # database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data.db3"

    mailer_transport:  smtp
    mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
    mailer_user:       ~
    mailer_password:   ~

    # A secret key that's used to generate certain security-related tokens
    secret:            fsdfsdfs5d4f8ers6f1re98f46r54e1f498zef151zer54f
```

And my Procfile

```
web: $(composer config bin-dir)/heroku-php-apache2 web/
```

A part of my config.yml: doctrine: dbal:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
```

> The whole trace after executing the git command: git push heroku
>   master

```
remote:        
remote:          - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.3.11)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:        
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
remote:        Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
remote:        > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
remote:        > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
remote:        
remote:                                                                                     
remote:          [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                              
remote:          An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                                                     
remote:        
remote:                                                     
remote:          [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]        
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                     
remote:        
remote:                                                     
remote:          [PDOException]                             
remote:          SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused  
remote:                                                     
remote:        
remote:        Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception
remote:        
remote:                                                                                         
remote:          [RuntimeException]                                                             
remote:          An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:      
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]                                
remote:            An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                          
remote:            SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:                                                                                         
remote:            [PDOException]                                                               
remote:            SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused                                    
remote:                                                                                         
remote:          .                                                                              
remote:                                                                                         
remote:        
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:        
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem will be with one of these parameters:

```
parameters:
    database_host:     sql7.freemysqlhosting.net
    database_port:     null
    database_name:     sql8125248
    database_user:     sql8125248
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_password: R2NgGhUjO8
```

I've changed the database_port to `null` because normally that's what should be used. Can you try with that set to null?

Also, can you verify all those other parameters are correct? Is there a web access interface that you can test those out.

Also does the database `sql8125248` actually exist? That can actually show errors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for quickly reply.
I try it and let you know in few minutes.

Comment: Same error @Alvin: "Push rejected to myapp".
Knowing that my free database is accessible, because I can see it via phpmyadmin.co as all others free database of freemysqlhosting.net.